# Freezing issue when loading multiplayer with Black Ops 2?

Tags: xbox-360, technical-issues, call-of-duty-black-ops-2

Whenever I start up Black Ops 2 it starts loading, but then freezes in multiplayer. Sometimes, it makes it to the 'public match' then freezes at that point instead.

What causes this? Can it be fixed? I play on Xbox 360.

Comment: Does this happen with any other games or just BO2? What state is your disc in (smudged/scratched)? How old is the console? What's the integrity of your internet connection like? We're going to need a bit more info. We're not magic

Comment: Like Ben said, most likely problem is the disk - is it smudged with fingerprints, or scratched? Put it optical-side up on a table, and give it a wipe with a soft cloth. Don't use water (if there's a particularly dirty spot, use your breath to fog it up a bit then wipe it off). Otherwise your Xbox's DVD drive may be playing up - if similar problems happen with other games, this is more likely the issue.

Comment: The disc has minor craches and I've already tried cleaning it